# Best way to filter HTML-file for certain Words

Tags: c#, html, filtering, html-agility-pack

I want to read and filter a HTML-file. My plan is to read the file line by line and only save lines that are "encapsulated" by the td tags (I cant copy them here because they wont show up for some reason).
For example:

```html
    <html>
      <head>
        <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>
              Tabelle Artikel</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <table width="900" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align:top;font-family:Arial;font-size:14pt;">
                  Tabelle <strong>Artikel</strong><span style="font-size:10pt;padding-left:10"><a href="_Index.html">Tabellen-Übersicht</a></span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align:top;font-family:Arial;font-size:.8em;padding-bottom:5;padding-left:30;">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" style="border:1px solid darkgray;width:100%">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="font-family:Arial; font-size:.9em;font-weight:bold;">Name</td>
                    <td style="font-family:Arial; font-size:.9em;font-weight:bold;">Label</td>
                    <td style="font-family:Arial; font-size:.9em;font-weight:bold;">Typ</td>
                    <td style="font-family:Arial; font-size:.9em;font-weight:bold;">MDT</td>
                    <td style="font-family:Arial; font-size:.9em;font-weight:bold;">Format</td>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr style="background-color:black;color:white;">
```

In this example only these lines that were encapsulated by the TD tags would be saved to the string

Its pretty straight forwards and easy if it werent for the fact that the encapsulated text might be large enough to be multiple lines long. This make it hard for me to filter it (Im a beginner).

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string line = "";
        string FilteredHTML = "";
        bool SaveLine = false;

        using (StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(@"FilePath"))
        {
            while ((line = Reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.Contains("<td") || SaveLine == true)
                {
                    {
                        FilteredHTML += line;
                        SaveLine = true;
                    }

                }
                if (line.Contains("</td>") && (!line.Contains("<td")))
                {
                    {
                        FilteredHTML += line;
                        SaveLine = false;
                    }              
                }
            }
        }
        while (FilteredHTML.Contains("  ")) FilteredHTML = FilteredHTML.Replace("  ", " ");
        string Output = "";
        string Delimiter = "</td>";
        var tokens = Regex.Split(FilteredHTML, Delimiter);
        foreach (var item in tokens)
        {
            Output = item;
            Output += Delimiter;
            Console.WriteLine(Output);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

This works to a certain extend but I still have Text before the  tags. And the fact that im Adding the Delimiter manually after using it also causes multiple  in a row to show up.

As you can see this is a mess and I tried my best to make it work but I cant help but think that there has to be a easier way to Filter HTML file for certain lines. 
I also tried to use the HTML-Agility pack but I didnt find anything that would help me with filtering out certain lines.

Comment: HtmlAgilityPack is the way to go, but you need to think in terms of HTML elements rather than lines - so you tell it to "get me all the `<td>` elements". It's not clear from your question what your desired output is, are you trying to grab the whole `<td>` element including the tags? What happens if the HTML is split over multiple lines?

Comment: have you tried  to load your html as an xml document and then xpath it ?

Comment: @stuartd yes exactly I was actually able to filter it with the HTML AgilityPack but I also removed the tags which I need for further filtering down the road. I didn't know that I could grab every <td> element with the htmlAgilityPack can you point me in a direction ?

Comment: It's complicated by the nested tables in your example. Which <td> elements are you trying to get?

Comment: @stuartd every single <td> element in the whole HTML file. I will filter them out later i'm trying to use the HTML agility pack right now but I keep getting System.NullReferenceExceptions

Comment: So when the <td> contains a sub-table, you'll have to drill down into that table..

Comment: @stuartd yea I got that down already I still cant figure out how to get all the <td> elements in the first place though. Im still getting the exception and I tried to parse it from a file, from a string and from a website but something is not working right

Comment: `doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table/tr/td")` ?

Comment: @stuartd thank you so much the SelectNode lines I tried didnt work for some reason.